# How to Fetch DataTable1 & DataTable2 Information using Relationship

Tags: vb.net, winforms, join, datatable

### Goal

I want to access the information of my child's table via the parent table. Using the image below, we can see that I have Conveying Solutions and for every Conveying Solution, I will have one or more Conveyor Functions related to it.

*Keep in mind, I'm not even sure my relationship has been done correctly below... I'm new to this.*

[image: Relationship]

---

### Attempt

I load the information into my DataTables (this works correctly) on the form load. I then set my DataView's table to my Conveying Solution's DataTable and set my DataView as the DataSource of my DataGridView.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private DataView1 As New DataView


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        clsConveyingSolution.LoadConveyingSolutions()
        clsConveyorFunction.LoadConveyorFunctions()

        Try
            DataView1.Table = HunterMgmt.dtConveyingSolutions
            DataGridView1.DataSource = DataView1
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

I'd like to perform some sort of join and have access to the information of both tables using the relationship that I established.

Comment: Firstly, forget the `DataView`.  Every `DataTable` already has one in its `DefaultView` property and that's where the data comes from when you bind a `DataTable`.  How else could you sort data in a `DataGridView` bound to a `DataTable`?  Add a `BindingSource` to your form in the designer, bind the `DataTable` to that and bind that to the grid.

Comment: As for the question, what do you mean by "some type of join"?  Do you actually want to join the data, i.e. create one result set with columns from both tables?  Do you just want to access child records given a particular parent record, e.g. display child records in a second grid and filter out all those not related to the currently selected parent?

Comment: @jmcilhinney What I mean by some type of join is I'd like to show the `ConveyorFunction.Name` in the same DataGridView that my DataTable `ConveyingSolutions` is bound to. In order to do this currently, I create the actual field `ConveyorFunctionName` in my `dtConveyingSolutions` and then set the name. I wanted to know if it was possible to do this with some type of join instead of creating an extra field in the DataTable.

Comment: So you want columns from both tables in the same row, right?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yep. You got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to join the data from the two tables then you have two main choices:

1. Add a new DataTable and table adapter to your DataSet based on a query that performs the join.  You would then treat that DataTable and table adapter the same way you would any other.
2. Use LINQ or some manual process to create a new list that joins the data from the rows of your existing DataTables.